# FB.ui with share_open_graph method displays small image only

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have this code to create multiple share buttons on a same page URL but specifying a custom title, description and image.

```
    // this loads the Facebook API
    (function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        var appId = '1937011929814387';
        FB.init({
            appId: appId,
            xfbml: true,
            version: 'v2.9'
        });
    };

    // FB Share with custom OG data.
    (function($) {

        $('.fb_share_btn').on('click', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();

                // Dynamically gather and set the FB share data. 
                var FBDesc      = 'My custom description';
                var FBTitle     = 'My custom title';
                var FBLink      = 'http://example.com/my-page-link';
                var FBPic       = 'http://example.com/img/my-custom-image.jpg';

                // Open FB share popup
                FB.ui({
                    method: 'share_open_graph',
                    action_type: 'og.shares',
                    action_properties: JSON.stringify({
                        object: {
                            'og:url': FBLink,
                            'og:title': FBTitle,
                            'og:description': FBDesc,
                            'og:image': FBPic
                        }
                    })
                },
                function (response) {
                // Action after response
                })
        })

    })( jQuery );
```

For the image, I'm following the "Sharing Best Practices" described here in the [FB dev docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images).

But when shared to Facebook, instead of displaying the image in big size like this:

[image]

It comes out in the smaller version like this:

[image]

I'm being aware that Facebook JavaScript SDK is [deprecating some parameters recently](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog#deprecated-params) that used to make this to work as I'm expecting. That's why I moved to use the latest SDK version (v2.9) and method available for this custom shares using [`share_open_graph` for share dialogs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog#open-graph).

Does this means that from SDK v2.9+, we cannot have the share tiles displaying a bigger image anymore?

Comment: What’s your app’s category - game, or other? For game apps, this is by design, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images

Comment: App category is Education.

Comment: I have the same problem! Also the category is Education. But what is interesting - when I share using my main fb account (the same which is owner of the app) the image is large. But when I use my testing account the image is small. :( 
If you find the solution, please write it here. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE 2019**
This solution doesn't work any more. New solution hasn't been found yet. :(

I found the solution. Just replace `action_type: 'og.shares'`, with `action_type: 'og.likes'`:

```
...
FB.ui({
        method: 'share_open_graph',
        action_type: 'og.likes',
        action_properties: JSON.stringify({
            object: {
                'og:url': FBLink,
                'og:title': FBTitle,
                'og:description': FBDesc,
                'og:image': FBPic
            }
        })
    },
    function (response) {
    // Action after response
    }
);
...
```

For complete article check: [Dynamically change facebook open graph meta data javascript](http://drib.tech/programming/dynamically-change-facebook-open-graph-meta-data-javascript) or just checkout [fully working example](http://drib.tech/fbsharetest/quiz.html) to see it in action.

The small downside is sentence like *"John Doe likes an object on drib"* at the top of share dialog and shared content on the user wall.

Comment: you absolute champion

Comment: This solution no longer works for some reason. Even the demo in the article linked above does not work anymore and I can't seem to find any other way to do this online.

Comment: @Serks Thank you for the comment - I updated the answer with the warning. Unfortunately it seems fb doesn't allow custom title, images, etc for the same URL any more.